# Oracle Pivoting returning Null values for Month/Year

Tags: oracle, null, pivot-table

I'm trying to pivoting this table by month/year according to date (field DT):

```
  CREATE TABLE "TEMP" 
   (    "NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
        "DT" DATE, 
        "SZ" NUMBER(10,0)
   )

Insert into TEMP (NAME,DT,SZ) values ('A',to_date('16/01/15','DD/MM/RR'),'1');
Insert into TEMP (NAME,DT,SZ) values ('B',to_date('16/01/15','DD/MM/RR'),'2');
Insert into TEMP (NAME,DT,SZ) values ('C',to_date('16/01/15','DD/MM/RR'),'3');
Insert into TEMP (NAME,DT,SZ) values ('D',to_date('16/01/15','DD/MM/RR'),'4');
Insert into TEMP (NAME,DT,SZ) values ('A',to_date('10/01/15','DD/MM/RR'),'5');
Insert into TEMP (NAME,DT,SZ) values ('B',to_date('10/01/15','DD/MM/RR'),'6');
Insert into TEMP (NAME,DT,SZ) values ('C',to_date('10/01/15','DD/MM/RR'),'7');
```

using this query:

```
SELECT * from
  (select name, sz, dt from temp) 
  pivot (sum(sz) for dt in (to_date('01/2015', 'MM/YYYY') as "dt"))
```

and I receive this:

```
NAME                         dt
-------------------- ----------
D                               
A                               
B                                
C
```

However, I was excepting to get:

```
NAME                         dt
-------------------- ----------
D                             4 
A                             6  
B                             8   
C                            10
```

I've tried many things but none of them seems to work as:

```
...
pivot (sum(sz) for dt in ('01/2015' as "dt")) --01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
```

Do you have a clue of what I'm doing wrong?

Any help is very welcome.

Comment: Why are you pivoting? I see no need, doesn't `select name, sum(sz) as dt from temp group by name` give you what you want?

Comment: Indeed, it has the same effect. But this is a very simple example of my real data. Actually, my real table can have several data in months/years and dozens of columns. So that won't work for a large period (more than one month). I really appreciate you help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `TO_CHAR` and not `TO_DATE`

```
WITH pivotdata AS 
( 
       SELECT name, 
              sz, 
              To_char(dt, 'MM/YYYY') dt1 
       FROM   temp ) 
SELECT * 
FROM   pivotdata pivot (SUM(sz) FOR dt1 IN ('01/2015') );
```

This will return

```
NAME    '01/2015'
D   4
A   6
B   8
C   10
```